# League of Legends only working when launching as administrator

Tags: league-of-legends, technical-issues

*Not a big issue but it's bugging me for some time now.*

After a re-install, I'm only able to launch the game as *Administrator*, otherwise, the launcher would throw the following error and close.

> Unspecified error. Check the logs for more info

I've tried to **Repair** it, to **set permissions of League's folder** to 777 *(everyone could do whatever they wanted to there)* and even **re-installing again** some months after it started happening.

Extra info:

- I don't use antivirus
- My OS is Win7

Comment: It might help to include the error message

Comment: It just says *Unspecified error. Check the logs for more info*

Comment: If you don't care that it runs as administrator, you could troubleshoot the program that launches League, and set it to run as administrator every time so you can avoid this.

Comment: @TimmyJim that's right, but not what I'm aiming to as it is the fact that it has to run as administrator to actually work what's bugging me.

Comment: Try disabling your antivirus and see if that works. If it does, then it means your antivirus is interfering. I have this problem personally (with MSE), and I can add a very detailed answer later. In short, to fix this I run as admin at all times (there is a separate admin launcher in the same folder you can use). I also have a `cmd` file that I run after every game update that gets a list of executable file locations. I then add those to my AV's exclusion list and remove the old ones.

Comment: Could you check your system event logs and see if there is anymore information on the error? There might be a folder else where that LoL needs access to that is set to admin only.

Comment: @Alex So did you determine if it's your antivirus? Also, what operating system are you on?

Comment: @mbomb007 updated question adding that info

Comment: @Alex Are you launching the old client or the beta client?

Comment: Old one, I guess

Comment: Where have you installed it to?

Comment: @sysfired Are you still having problems?

Comment: Since the OP hasn't included enough info or responded to our questions, I'm voting to close as unclear.

Comment: Sorry, I just uninstalled LoL a while ago, was launching as administrator the whole time..

Answer (score 1):

That's interesting. Have you updated to the new client? That one doesn't have an option to run it as administrator. Now that it's out, I would suggest uninstalling League of Legends trough `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features` and [reinstalling](https://signup.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/signup/redownload) it. The first time you run it, be sure to run `lol.launcher.admin.exe`, wait for the patch to finish, then click on [LEAGUE CLIENT UPDATE OPEN BETA / Upgrade Now](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/784976911.png). In the future, start League of Legends using `LeagueClient.exe` and it should work without asking for administrator privileges.

Comment: Any program can be run as an admin by right-clicking it. The old client just came with an .exe that was already preset to run as an admin for whatever reason.